# Why does my entire article spill out of it's border when it's in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, blogs

So I've been trying to use flexbox to make a sidebar for my blog, however, when I zoomed out, all the contents of my article spilled out of the border like this:

messed up webpage

[image: messed up webpage]

I've tried to use this piece of code: `word-wrap: break-word;` to fix the problem before, but it doesn't seem to work and I can't seem to find any other solution. 
Heres my piece of code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: wayward;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 100% overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: static;
  left: 900px;
  border: 2px hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flex-grid {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto -1rem 1rem;
}

.col {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sidebar {
  margin-left: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.main {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 29.25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  flex: 3;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Titanic Movie Review 1996
  <h1>
    <h3> -By Harold Hon</h3>
    <div class="flex-grid">
      <aside class="col sidebar">
        <h2>The Sidebar</h2>
        <p>In CSS, it has a flex property of 1, meaning it takes up 1 unit (whatever that might be) of the available space.
          <p>

      </aside>
      <section class="col main">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://static3.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Rose-DeWitt-Bukater-and-Jack.png?q=50&fit=crop&w=767&h=450&dpr=1.5" alt="An Image of Jack holding rose  from behind">
        </div>

        <p>The Titanic is a classic movie filmed in 1996, with jack and rose, it is a classic tradgedy and feautures kate and leonardo da vinci, one is poor, one is rich, the girl has a expensive random amulet that look quite cool i think, yeah, and then
          the ships crashes and they all die! except for rose. And heres a random movie review from somewhere: <br>
          <br> Like a great iron Sphinx on the ocean floor, the Titanic faces still toward the West, interrupted forever on its only voyage. We see it in the opening shots of “Titanic,” encrusted with the silt of 85 years; a remote-controlled TV camera
          snakes its way inside, down corridors and through doorways, showing us staterooms built for millionaires and inherited by crustaceans.<br><br> These shots strike precisely the right note; the ship calls from its grave for its story to be told,
          and if the story is made of showbiz and hype, smoke and mirrors--well, so was the Titanic. She was “the largest moving work of man in all history,” a character boasts, neatly dismissing the Pyramids and the Great Wall. There is a shot of her,
          early in the film, sweeping majestically beneath the camera from bow to stern, nearly 900 feet long and “unsinkable,” it was claimed, until an iceberg made an irrefutable reply.
          <br><br> James Cameron's 194-minute, $200 million film of the tragic voyage is in the tradition of the great Hollywood epics. It is flawlessly crafted, intelligently constructed, strongly acted and spellbinding. If its story stays well within
          the traditional formulas for such pictures, well, you don't choose the most expensive film ever made as your opportunity to reinvent the wheel.<br><br> We know before the movie begins that certain things must happen. We must see the Titanic
          sail and sink, and be convinced we are looking at a real ship. There must be a human story--probably a romance--involving a few of the passengers. There must be vignettes involving some of the rest and a subplot involving the arrogance and pride
          of the ship's builders--and perhaps also their courage and dignity. And there must be a reenactment of the ship's terrible death throes; it took two and a half hours to sink, so that everyone aboard had time to know what was happening, and to
          consider their actions.<br><br> All of those elements are present in Cameron's “Titanic,” weighted and balanced like ballast, so that the film always seems in proportion. The ship was made out of models (large and small), visual effects and
          computer animation. You know intellectually that you're not looking at a real ocean liner--but the illusion is convincing and seamless. The special effects don't call inappropriate attention to themselves but get the job done.<br><br> The human
          story involves an 17-year-old woman named Rose DeWitt Bukater (Kate Winslet) who is sailing to what she sees as her own personal doom: She has been forced by her penniless mother to become engaged to marry a rich, supercilious snob named Cal
          Hockley (Billy Zane), and so bitterly does she hate this prospect that she tries to kill herself by jumping from the ship. She is saved by Jack Dawson (Leonardo DiCaprio), a brash kid from steerage, and of course they will fall in love during
          the brief time left to them.<br><br> The screenplay tells their story in a way that unobtrusively shows off the ship. Jack is invited to join Rose's party at dinner in the first class dining room, and later, fleeing from Cal's manservant, Lovejoy
          (David Warner), they find themselves first in the awesome engine room, with pistons as tall as churches, and then at a rousing Irish dance in the crowded steerage. (At one point Rose gives Lovejoy the finger; did young ladies do that in 1912?)
          Their exploration is intercut with scenes from the command deck, where the captain (Bernard Hill) consults with Andrews (Victor Garber), the ship's designer and Ismay (Jonathan Hyde), the White Star Line's managing director.<br><br>

        </p>
      </section>












      </body>

      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to close the h1 tag and forgot to close the div with the class "flex-grid" and also also,

in the styling, you can't keep the body styling inside the * styling, and you forgot to put a semi-colon after "height:100%" in the body styling.

I added the html, head and body tags in the final code

Based on the the code you seem to be learning html and css, if you're using vs code then i would suggest installing the extension prettier which will throw an error if the synatax is incorrect

Here's the final code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: wayward;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: static;
  left: 900px;
  border: 2px hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flex-grid {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto -1rem 1rem;
}

.col {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sidebar {
  margin-left: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.main {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 29.25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  flex: 3;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Titanic Movie Review 1996</h1>
  <h3>-By Harold Hon</h3>
  <div class="flex-grid">
    <aside class="col sidebar">
      <h2>The Sidebar</h2>
      <p>
        In CSS, it has a flex property of 1, meaning it takes up 1 unit (whatever that might be) of the available space.
      </p>
    </aside>
    <section class="col main">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://static3.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Rose-DeWitt-Bukater-and-Jack.png?q=50&fit=crop&w=767&h=450&dpr=1.5" alt="An Image of Jack holding rose  from behind" />
      </div>

      <p>
        The Titanic is a classic movie filmed in 1996, with jack and rose, it is a classic tradgedy and feautures kate and leonardo da vinci, one is poor, one is rich, the girl has a expensive random amulet that look quite cool i think, yeah, and then the ships
        crashes and they all die! except for rose. And heres a random movie review from somewhere:
        <br />
        <br /> Like a great iron Sphinx on the ocean floor, the Titanic faces still toward the West, interrupted forever on its only voyage. We see it in the opening shots of “Titanic,” encrusted with the silt of 85 years; a remote-controlled TV camera
        snakes its way inside, down corridors and through doorways, showing us staterooms built for millionaires and inherited by crustaceans.<br /><br /> These shots strike precisely the right note; the ship calls from its grave for its story to be told,
        and if the story is made of showbiz and hype, smoke and mirrors--well, so was the Titanic. She was “the largest moving work of man in all history,” a character boasts, neatly dismissing the Pyramids and the Great Wall. There is a shot of her,
        early in the film, sweeping majestically beneath the camera from bow to stern, nearly 900 feet long and “unsinkable,” it was claimed, until an iceberg made an irrefutable reply. <br /><br /> James Cameron's 194-minute, $200 million film of the
        tragic voyage is in the tradition of the great Hollywood epics. It is flawlessly crafted, intelligently constructed, strongly acted and spellbinding. If its story stays well within the traditional formulas for such pictures, well, you don't choose
        the most expensive film ever made as your opportunity to reinvent the wheel.<br /><br /> We know before the movie begins that certain things must happen. We must see the Titanic sail and sink, and be convinced we are looking at a real ship. There
        must be a human story--probably a romance--involving a few of the passengers. There must be vignettes involving some of the rest and a subplot involving the arrogance and pride of the ship's builders--and perhaps also their courage and dignity.
        And there must be a reenactment of the ship's terrible death throes; it took two and a half hours to sink, so that everyone aboard had time to know what was happening, and to consider their actions.<br /><br /> All of those elements are present
        in Cameron's “Titanic,” weighted and balanced like ballast, so that the film always seems in proportion. The ship was made out of models (large and small), visual effects and computer animation. You know intellectually that you're not looking
        at a real ocean liner--but the illusion is convincing and seamless. The special effects don't call inappropriate attention to themselves but get the job done.<br /><br /> The human story involves an 17-year-old woman named Rose DeWitt Bukater
        (Kate Winslet) who is sailing to what she sees as her own personal doom: She has been forced by her penniless mother to become engaged to marry a rich, supercilious snob named Cal Hockley (Billy Zane), and so bitterly does she hate this prospect
        that she tries to kill herself by jumping from the ship. She is saved by Jack Dawson (Leonardo DiCaprio), a brash kid from steerage, and of course they will fall in love during the brief time left to them.<br /><br /> The screenplay tells their
        story in a way that unobtrusively shows off the ship. Jack is invited to join Rose's party at dinner in the first class dining room, and later, fleeing from Cal's manservant, Lovejoy (David Warner), they find themselves first in the awesome engine
        room, with pistons as tall as churches, and then at a rousing Irish dance in the crowded steerage. (At one point Rose gives Lovejoy the finger; did young ladies do that in 1912?) Their exploration is intercut with scenes from the command deck,
        where the captain (Bernard Hill) consults with Andrews (Victor Garber), the ship's designer and Ismay (Jonathan Hyde), the White Star Line's managing director.<br /><br />
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```